# R creating a new vector based on a count of values up to the first instance of a value an existing vector

Tags: r, count

How might I create a new variable "CountWK" that is based on a count of the values in "WK" that occur up until the first instance of "1" in "Performance" grouped by "ID"?

```
ID<-c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C')
WK<-c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Performance<-c(0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1)
Data<-data.frame(ID, WK, Performance)
```

So, for ID "A" CountWk would be "2", for "B" "2", and for C "2" with value of N/A in "CountWk" for every other row besides the one that contains the first instance of "1" in "Performance".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>% 
     group_by(ID) %>% 
     mutate(CountWk= ifelse(cumsum(Performance==1)==1 & Performance!=0,
                 WK, NA_real_))
#    ID WK Performance CountWk
#1   A  1           0      NA
#2   A  2           1       2
#3   A  3           1      NA
#4   B  1           0      NA
#5   B  2           1       2
#6   B  3           0      NA
#7   C  1           0      NA
#8   C  2           1       2
#9   C  3           0      NA
#10  C  4           1      NA
#11  C  5           1      NA
```

Or without the `ifelse`

```
  Data %>%
      group_by(ID) %>%
      mutate(CountWk= (NA^!(cumsum(Performance==1)==1 & Performance!=0)) *WK)
```

Or using `base R`

```
 Data$CountWk <- with(Data, (NA^!(ave(Performance==1, ID, FUN=cumsum)==1&
                        Performance!=0)) * WK)
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt solutions and alternatives!

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I would approach this using the `data.table` package

First find the row index using `.I` and `match`

```
library(data.table)
indx <- setDT(Data)[, .I[match(1L, Performance)], by = ID]$V1
```

Then assign `WK` to `CountWk` by that index

```
Data[indx, CountWk := WK][]
#     ID WK Performance CountWk
#  1:  A  1           0      NA
#  2:  A  2           1       2
#  3:  A  3           1      NA
#  4:  B  1           0      NA
#  5:  B  2           1       2
#  6:  B  3           0      NA
#  7:  C  1           0      NA
#  8:  C  2           1       2
#  9:  C  3           0      NA
# 10:  C  4           1      NA
# 11:  C  5           1      NA
```

Comment: also, `setDT(Data)[Performance == 1, coutWK := c(WK[1L], rep(NA, .N-1L)), by=ID]` would work I think.

Comment: Thanks for prompt solutions!